# ExecuteExcel4Macro to print closed workbook

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I managed to get data out of a workbook with the ExecuteExcel4Macro.
But can i print the one sheet in the file, without opening the file?

Comment: I don't think so. Even if you use `ShellExecute` to print it, the workbook will still be opened, printed and then closed.

Comment: Ok but how than I don't want to see Just print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the API version:

```
 Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
                                      (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
                                       ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Const SW_HIDE            As Long = 0&
Sub PrintFile(strFilepath As String)
   ShellExecute Application.hWnd, "Print", strFilepath, 0&, 0&, SW_HIDE
End Sub
```

Your calling code then just uses:

```
Call PrintFile("C:\path to file.xls")
```

for example.